# Is there a way to decrease the height of chrome's address and tab bar in macOS?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm on a 13" Macbook Pro and this thing is taking a lot of screen space... I've seen some solutions for Windows users and Firefox has a compact UI checkbox... Any advice?

Comment: I don't think so but you could try this browser with a super compact UI https://minbrowser.org the browser behind it is the same as Chrome I think. Going into fullscreen mode on macOS also gives you more space to browse the web.

Comment: *minibrowser* looks so cool and elegant! I have to stay on chrome tho as there's no replacement for node debugging with dev tools. Thank you for your recommendation still!